# Function argument within a string

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am attempting to create a function, which would make me easily plot data by a given year from dataframe with data for many years. I have succeeded in doing this. However, I also want the given year to be shown in the title, but can't figure out how to put an argument into the title string.

For simplicity, I will just show a mock function:

```
my_plot <- function(x){
v1 <- x:10
return(plot(v1, main = "The year of ...y..."))
}
my_plot(x=4)
```

[image]

How do I replace ...y... with an function argument?

Best,
Rikki

Comment: FYI `plot()` plots as a side effect, your function is in fact always returning `NULL`

Comment: The graph was made using the given mock function, so I guess it is not returning NULL?

Comment: It is plotting, but it does return NULL, try `foo <- my_plot(x=4);foo`

Comment: your return() call doesn't hurt but it's a bit misleading, since your function is only called for side effects. I understand this can be confusing, for example ggplot produces real plot objects that you can store in variables. bas exploiting is not like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste()` to combine two different strings:

```
my_plot <- function(x, year){
v1 <- x:10
return(plot(v1, main = paste("The year of", year))
}
my_plot(x=4)
```

Comment: `sep` doesn't seem needed here. `paste()` is a good way to do it, I also like `sprintf("The year of &s", year)`, and then there's also `glue::glue("The year of {year}")`

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I had completely forgotten about the paste function.

Comment: @moodymudskipper Right, that was a mistake, idk why I added a comma. Thanks!